# HighCharts Combined Stack column bar, group column, and line chart

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to have a combined stack column bar, group column with a line chart.
Basically I would like the ability to combine the following:
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-stacked-and-grouped/

```
Stacked column with combined bar
```

and

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/combo-dual-axes/

Comment: Do you mean something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/0ynhb8rz/ ?

Comment: @SebastianBochan - Yes but with another axis for the line!

Comment: You need to add yAxis as array and then refer to index of them in particular serie. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/0ynhb8rz/1/